# How to construct deep query in ebean

Tags: playframework-2.0, datatables, ebean

I’m using ebean and play 2.2.3 I’ve got these model classes(trimmed them down for clarity)

Student

```java
public class Student extends Model implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    public String id;

    @Column(name = "reg_no",  unique=true)
    public String regNo;

    @NotNull
    @Required
    @Column(name = "first_name")
    public String firstName;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "student")
    private List<StudentClass> studentClassList;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "student")
    private List<StudentLevelDetails> studentLevelDetailsList;

    public static Finder<String, Student> find = new Finder<String, Student>(
        String.class, Student.class);
}
```

Levels

```java
public class Levels extends Model implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "id")
    public Integer id;

    @Size(max = 255)
    @Column(name = "name", unique=true)

    public String name;

    public static Model.Finder<Integer, Levels> find = new Finder<Integer, Levels>(
        Integer.class, Levels.class);
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "level")
    private List<StudentLevelDetails> studentLevelDetailsList;
}
```

Classes

```java
public class Classes extends Model implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")

    public Integer id;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Required
    @Column(name = "name", unique=true)
    public String name;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "class1")
    public List<StudentClass> studentClassList;

    public static Finder<Integer, Classes> find = 
                    new Finder<>(Integer.class, Classes.class);
}
```

Student_Level_Details

```java
@Table(name = "student_level_details", uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {
    "student", "type" }))
public class StudentLevelDetails extends Model implements Serializable {

    public static enum Type {
        @EnumValue("CL")
        CURRENT_LEVEL,

       @EnumValue("LAI")
       LEVEL_ADMITTED_INTO
    }


    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull

    @Column(name = "id")
    public Integer id;

    @Size(max = 2147483647)
    @Column(name = "type")
    public Type type;

    @JoinColumn(name = "student", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    public Student student;

    @JoinColumn(name = "level", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    public Levels level;

    public static final Finder<Integer, StudentLevelDetails> find = new Finder<Integer, StudentLevelDetails>(
        Integer.class, StudentLevelDetails.class);
}
```

Student_Class

```java
@Table(name = "student_class", uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"student", "type"}))
public class StudentClass extends Model implements Serializable {
    public static enum Type {
        @EnumValue("CC")
        CURRENT_CLASS
    }

    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "id")
    public Integer id;

    @JoinColumn(name = "student", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    public Student student;

    @JoinColumn(name = "class", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    public Classes class1;

    @Column(name = "type")
    public Type type;
}
```

i'm using datatables, i want to construct a query that will return data for the table based on the filter value from the search box. 
How do i construct this kind of query in ebean(i explain the query intention in plain english)

select firstName from student where firstName like "search filter" or level.name like "search filter" or class1.name like "search filter" where level.Type = CURRENT_LEVEL and class1.Type = "CURRENT_CLASS".

so basically what confuses me is how to join the tables to give one resulting table

thanks.